# Classic ASP/VBScript implementation of Crockford's Base32 Encoding

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Moving on from [the first part of my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297020/), I'm now working on trying to write a Classic ASP/VBScript implementation of [Douglas Crockford's Base32 Encoding](http://www.crockford.com/wrmg/base32.html).

Time is tight on this particular project, so while I am working this out on my own, I'm hoping someone has something readily at hand (or can at least whip one up faster than I can).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First run... does this look about right?

```
'Base32 encoding functions for shorter, less confusing verification numbers'
Const kBase32Digits = "0123456789abcdefghjkmnpqrstvwxyz"
'To Base32'
Function ToBase32(ByVal lInput)
    Dim lModulo, sTemp
    Do Until lInput = 0
        lModulo = lInput Mod 32
        sTemp = Mid(kBase32Digits, lModulo + 1, 1) & sTemp
        lInput = lInput \ 32
    Loop
    ToBase32 = sTemp
End Function
'From Base32'
Function FromBase32(ByVal sInput)
    Dim sTemp, sR, i,iY,lLen, zMultiplier
    sTemp = LCase(sInput)
    sTemp = Replace(sTemp,"o","0")
    sTemp = Replace(sTemp,"i","1")
    sTemp = Replace(sTemp,"l","1")
    sTemp = Replace(sTemp,"u","v")
    zMultiplier = 1
    lLen = Len(sTemp)
    For i = lLen To 1 Step -1
        sR = Mid(sTemp, i, 1)
        iY = InStr(1, kBase32Digits, sR, vbTextCompare) - 1
        FromBase32 = FromBase32 + iY * zMultiplier
        zMultiplier = zMultiplier * 32
    Next
End Function
```

**Edit:** Seems to work fine so far... I'll go with this unless someone posts something better.

Answer (score 1):

the chosen answer may work, but note

[TOTP Base32 vs Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082075/totp-base32-vs-base64)

> One important and simple reason and why Base32 even exists is that it uses A-Z uppercase only (no lowercase) and the numbers 2-7. No 0189. 26 + 6 chars = 32.

Hence, I would change the constant:

```
Const kBase32Digits = "234567ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

Comment: For various TOTP implementations, sure. The article in the original question cited _We chose a symbol set of 10 digits and 22 letters. We exclude 4 of the 26 letters: I L O U_. Since it was intended to be an implementation of the article, I used that constant.