# How to Correctly Call TOTP Func in Data.OTP?

Tags: haskell, one-time-password, totp

When I use the secret key "abcdefghijklmnop" in Google Authenticator (Android), Microsoft Authenticator (Android) and oathtool (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS), I get matching Time-based One-Time Password (TOTP) values.  Unfortunately, I do not get a matching TOTP value when I use the same key in the following Haskell code (whether that be on Windows 10 or Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.OTP
import Data.Time.Clock

main = do
    -- This key is just for testing purposes
    let theSecretKey = "abcdefghijklmnop"

    -- See http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OTP-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-OTP.html#g:2
    curTime <- getCurrentTime
    let theTOTP = totp SHA1 theSecretKey curTime 30 6
    print theTOTP
```

I reckon this means the above code has a bug.  If I were to hazard a guess, either "theSecretKey" or "curTime" is being passed in an invalid format, but I'm not sure which.

What should I change in the above code to correctly call the totp function?

*NOTE: While testing with oathtool, I was able to verify that I should be using the SHA1 hashing algorithm*

Comment: Can you clarify? When you get the values from Google Authenticator and Microsoft Authenticator, you are using the **same** value of _curTime_ as you are in the Haskell code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure where Google Authenticator and Microsoft Authenticator for Android are getting the time from.  The above Haskell code is running on Windows 10 though.  I just ran getCurrentTime on WinCHCi at 3:35 PM CDT and got this back which seems right: 2020-01-14 21:35:01.9539814 UTC    I'm not sure what to do with the milliseconds though.  The example on the Data.OTP site does not show milliseconds.

Comment: I confirmed via oathtool that the algorithm should be likely be SHA1.   I'm editing my question to remove the references to SHA512 and SHA256.

Comment: The issue is that the TOTP result is intimately dependent on the time passed in. That means that you cannot directly compare a TOTP from two different authorities because they will use different times, hence will return different values.

Comment: The TOTP I'm getting on Android via Windows and Google Authenticator is identical to the TOTP I'm getting in UBuntu via oathtool on separate machine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you aren't getting the correct output is, the [`Base32`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082075/totp-base32-vs-base64) encoding used by the apps and tools you mentioned above for the secret key. Therefore, I would suggest you to decode the secret key with `Base32` decryption and then apply the `totp` function to get the correct TOTP value.

The [`decodeBase32`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base32-0.2.2.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Base32-Hex.html#v:decodeBase32) function from the package `Data.ByteString.Base32` can come handy when decoding the key.