# Why ASP.Identy encodes SecurityStamp using Base32 (internal implementation)

Tags: security, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm considering Base64 to store SecurityStamp within my user aggregate. Before entering a pitfall I'm trying to understand reasons why ASP team chosen to use Base32 instead of simply using Base64.

SecurityStamp is not something human should read or pass manually in requests. I cannot find any obvious advantage in adding internal Base32 implementation rather than using existing Base64.

```
private static string NewSecurityStamp()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[20];
        _rng.GetBytes(bytes);
        return Base32.ToBase32(bytes);
    }
```

> https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L2438

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the alphabet [Base32 is using](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/Base32.cs#L12), you will notice it's all capital letters and `234567`. This is done to specifically reduce human error when transferring the code (see more background in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57325779/12339804)).

When you further examine the `UserManager` source code, you will see that `NewSecurityStamp` is referenced by [`GenerateNewAuthenticatorKey`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L2240) which I believe is intended to provide human readable output (to, say, set up a 2FA when you've got no QR code to scan).

Comment: For authentication-key it does make sense but for security-stamp it does not introduce any value. As I mentioned in question it is not supposed to be read or used directly by end user. More to the topic base64 is more efficient when it comes to size.