# Decryption function gives wrong result with special characters

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm building an encryption/decryption function in VBScript / Classic ASP.
It all works as long as the string to be encrypted/decrypted does not contain special characters.

```
' str = "Bayern München"
' key = "ab34ehyd67hy6752daskjh"

Function EncryptString(val, key)

    valLen = Len(val)
    keyLen = Len(key)
    keyPos = 1
    newVal = ""
    revVal = val

    For x = 1 To valLen
        calc = AscW(Mid(revVal, x, 1)) + AscW(Mid(key, keyPos, 1))
        'Response.Write ":" & AscW(Mid(revVal, x, 1)) & " + " & AscW(Mid(key, keyPos, 1)) & " = " & calc & "<br />"
        newVal = newVal & Hex(calc)
        keyPos = keyPos + 1
        If keyPos > keyLen Then keyPos = 1
    Next

    EncryptString = newVal

End Function

Function DecryptString(val, key)

    ' The workaround - start
    For i = 160 To 255
        val = Replace(val, Chr(i), "&#" & i & ";")
    Next
    ' The workaround - end

    valLen = Len(val)
    keyLen = Len(key)
    keyPos = 1
    newVal = ""
    revVal = val
    chrVal = ""

    ' I suspect this to be the error
    For y = 1 To valLen Step 2
        chrVal = chrVal & ChrW("&h" & Mid(revVal, y, 2))
    Next

    For x = 1 To Len(chrVal)
        calc = AscW(Mid(chrVal, x, 1)) - AscW(Mid(key, keyPos, 1))
        'Response.Write "::" & AscW(Mid(chrVal, x, 1)) & " - " & AscW(Mid(key, keyPos, 1)) & " = " & calc & "<br />"
        newVal = newVal & ChrW(calc)
        keyPos = keyPos + 1
        If keyPos > keyLen Then keyPos = 1
    Next

    DecryptString = newVal

End Function
```

If I do an encryption of the string "Bayern München" and afterwards call the DecryptString function on the encrypted string, it returns `Bayern M?À?vU?`.

If I output the data (the Response.Write's in the example), the decryption function returns a negative number for the character `ü`, so I'm doing something wrong - but what?

The system encoding is Windows-1252.

**UPDATE:**

I did this workaround in the DecryptString function. I'm not sure if it covers all possible problems, but from my testing so far it does:

```
For i = 160 To 255
    val = Replace(val, Chr(i), "&#" & i & ";")
Next
```

Comment: Generally speaking I recommend using UTF-8 encoding throughout. Add ' CODEPAGE="65001"' to the declaration at the top of the page, and seeing as the string "Bayern München" is hard coded into your page you should save the file as UTF-8.  (You can do this with notepad, select "Save As" from the file menu and then use the drop down to change from ASCII to UTF-8 if necessary)
This blog post is essential reading for using Classic ASP/VBS in languages other than English.
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx

Comment: @john I'd wish I could do that, but it's an older system build on and expecting Windows-1252 encoding, so a conversion now is not possible.

Comment: @Lankymart it's my own question? :)

Comment: @Mads exactly, it's the same issue.

Comment: How is that? The original question was about getting the same encryption result in two systems, one running VBScript and one running C#. This is about not getting the right decryption value in VBScript.

Comment: But I get the right result, if I encrypt/decrypt `Bayern M&#252;nchen` so the question is, how I can convert the original value `Bayern München` to UTF-8 before encrypting/decrypting it? Converting the whole system to UTF-8 is not an option, I'm afraid.

Comment: @mads That comes down to understanding the page and how it interacts with your encryption/decryption methods. Is the page displaying UTF-8 data if it is the page should be processed as UTF-8 and have its responses written in UTF-8. Specifying HTML entity codes are just a hack for failure to encode the content correctly. See [Understanding How IIS Processes ASP Encoding](//stackoverflow.com/a/34356187)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still need to fix it, but all above is because [hex()](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_hex.asp) returns a string longer than 2 for any decimal over 255:

```
(255)10 = (FF)16
(256)10 = (100)16
```

i.e. when original string + salt is over 255(10)

```
("ü" 252) + ("6" 54) = 252+54 = 306(10)=132(16) (3 characters long)
```

then `"For y=1 To valLen Step 2"` will take only "13" of "132" which will result to improper decryption.

Depends on the need, it can be "fixed", for example, by checking if encrypted code is over 255 and when true, do not add salt:

```
Function EncryptString(val, key)

...
'newVal = newVal & Hex(calc) <-- replace this by following code
if calc > 255 then 
   newVal = newVal & "01" & Hex(Asc(Mid(revVal, x, 1))) ' no salt
else
   newVal = newVal & Hex(calc)
end if
```

where "01" is just a "signal" character that tells that the next char will be without salt.

Respectively,

```
Function DecryptString(val, key)
...
'calc = Asc(Mid(chrVal, x, 1)) - Asc(Mid(key, keyPos, 1))
if Asc(Mid(chrVal, x, 1))=1 then 'determine "signal"
   ignorenext = true 'flag that next char has no salt
else
   if ignorenext then
      calc = Asc(Mid(chrVal, x, 1)) 'no salt
      ignorenext = false
   else 
       calc = Asc(Mid(chrVal, x, 1)) - Asc(Mid(key, keyPos, 1))
   end if 

   newVal = newVal & Chr(calc)
   keyPos = keyPos + 1
   If keyPos > keyLen Then keyPos = 1
end if
```

Note, for Windows-1252 no need to use AscW()/ChrW() which are unicode specific.

Another approach will be to replace hexadecimal by something more "stable" i.e. base32. Taking sample code from [Classic ASP/VBScript implementation of Crockford's Base32 Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300846/classic-asp-vbscript-implementation-of-crockfords-base32-encoding) your code can look like

```
Function EncryptString(val, key)

    valLen = Len(val)
    keyLen = Len(key)
    keyPos = 1
    newVal = ""
    revVal = val

    For x = 1 To valLen
        calc = Asc(Mid(revVal, x, 1)) + Asc(Mid(key, keyPos, 1)) 
        newVal = newVal & ToBase32(calc) 
        keyPos = keyPos + 1
        If keyPos > keyLen Then keyPos = 1
    Next

    EncryptString = ucase(newVal)

End Function

Function DecryptString(val, key)

    valLen = Len(val)
    keyLen = Len(key)
    keyPos = 1
    newVal = ""
    revVal = val
    chrVal = ""

    For y = 1 To valLen Step 2 
        chrVal = chrVal & fromBase32(Mid(revVal, y, 2))  
        calc = fromBase32(Mid(revVal, y, 2)) - Asc(Mid(key, keyPos, 1))   
        newVal = newVal & Chr(calc) 
        keyPos = keyPos + 1
        If keyPos > keyLen Then keyPos = 1  
    Next

    DecryptString = newVal

End Function
```